# Python Django Logging Issue

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, logging

I have set up a Python Django projects. I have made a number of web services. But sometimes the data being logged is somewhat large and it takes like 3-4 seconds to log due to which response of service is delayed for few seconds which is a big factor in terms of performance.

**Question:** I was just wondering how can I make logging kind of asynchronous? Does Django provide like an option for this? OR do I have to take some other approach and handle it myself like open another thread and do logging in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QueueHandler` amd `QueueListener` which are available for Python 2.x through the [`logutils`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logutils) package. [This post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/improved-queuehandler-queuelistener.html) has more details, as do [the relevant Python 3.x docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#queuehandler).